# jQuery ui autocomplete suggestion list click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a jQuery autocomplete that works fine making the suggestions but when I click on an item in the suggestion list I can't get any event to fire.

I also have a keyup even on the same textbox to fill a listbox with data based on the input.  What I need to happen is fire the same thing that fires on keyup when an autocomplete suggestion is clicked.  It works with down arrow selection but not mouse click.

Here is the asp.net code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Width="450px" />
```

This is the jquery for the autocomplete:

```
$("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../WebServices/ModelSearch.asmx/JquerySearchSrn',
                data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('|')[0],
                            val: item.split('|')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function(response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function() {
            debugger;
            $('#<%=lsResults.ClientID %>').children().remove();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //data: "{ prefixText: '" + $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').val() + "', count: '5'}",
                data: "{ sText: '" + $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').val() + "', sFilter: '" + $('#<%=ddlProductLine.ClientID %>').val() + "'}",
                url: "../WebServices/ModelSearch.asmx/GetResults",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    //debugger;
                    var results = data.d;
                    //alert(results.length.toString());
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        var listItems = [];
                        var j = 1;
                        //for (var i in results) {
                        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 2) {
                            //debugger;
                            listItems.push('<option value="' +
                            results[i] + '">' + results[j]
                            + '</option>');
                            //key + '">' + results[key].text
                            //i++;
                            j += 2;
                        }
                        $('#<%=lsResults.ClientID %>').append(listItems.join(''));
                        $('#<%=lsResults.ClientID %>').attr('size', 10);
                        /* test event.type and event.target to capture only select control changes */
                    }
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },

        minLength: 2
    });
```

I also have this as the keyup event for txtSearch:

```
$('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').keyup(function() {

        if ($('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').val().length > 1) {
            $('#<%=lsResults.ClientID %>').children().remove();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //data: "{ prefixText: '" + $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').val() + "', count: '5'}",
                data: "{ sText: '" + $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').val() + "', sFilter: '" + $('#<%=ddlProductLine.ClientID %>').val() + "'}",
                url: "../WebServices/ModelSearch.asmx/GetResults",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    //debugger;
                    var results = data.d;
                    //alert(results.length.toString());
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        var listItems = [];
                        var j = 1;
                        //for (var i in results) {
                        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 2) {
                            //debugger;
                            listItems.push('<option value="' +
                            results[i] + '">' + results[j]
                            + '</option>');
                            //key + '">' + results[key].text
                            //i++;
                            j += 2;
                        }
                        $('#<%=lsResults.ClientID %>').append(listItems.join(''));
                        $('#<%=lsResults.ClientID %>').attr('size', 10);
                        /* test event.type and event.target to capture only select control changes */
                    }
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

I have tried just calling the .keyup function of the txtSearch so I wouldn't have to duplicate the code but it doesn't work unless I do it in Chrome's JavaScript console. How can I make this function properly?

Comment: Does the `debugger` statement fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your reply.  I tried to select event but it wouldn't work for me.

I solved it by targeting the class of the li tags that are rendered as suggestions.  The select function wouldn't fire the keyup event I needed to call.  This is what I did:

```
$('.ui-corner-all').click(function() {
   $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').keyup();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI plugin triggers events on some actions. The name of the event is prepended with the plugin name. So for the `select`event, you can bind to `autocompleteselect'.

By looking at the source code, you can see a `select`and a `change` event are fired.

```
var myHandler = function() { ... };


$("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>")
   .autocomplete({...})
   .bind('autocompleteselect', myHandler);
```

---

**Edit:** missunderstood a bit the question, hope i got it right now. If you want the same function to be called in the `select` handler and on keyup, declare it as above and specify it for both handlers:

```
var getResults= function() { ... /* execute ajax */ ... };


$("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>")
   .autocomplete({
       source: [],
       select: function() {
           ...
           getResults();
           ...
       }
    })
   .keyup(function() {
       // check the type of key that was pressed
       // (to avoid initiate an ajax request if the user pushed "num lock" for inst.)

       if (keyIsOk) {

           // work with a setTimeout, to try avoid messing up if a user types too fast
           getResults();
       }
   });
```

Although, firing an ajax request on each keyup might not be a good idea, this will generate a lot of requests.

d.

Comment: You can also define event handlers inside the widget instantiation code, which the OP has. This shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Missunderstood a bit the question. I've edited my answer, hope it's more what he's looking after.

Comment: It does create a lot of requests but this is the only way to make it fire without using change and having to leave the focus of the text box.  I need it to update the listbox below the autocomplete search field without leaving the textbox.